# NameError: name is not defined, even when I define the name

Tags: python, algorithm, defined

I'm writing a program that parses through a text matching a pattern to the text using the BoyerMoore algorithm. I managed to get the code to find all matches, and print out the position of the matches.

Now I also tried to get the length of the match_table and the number of comparisons. I'm quite unfamiliar with python, and the program tells me "NameError: name 'comparison' is not defined, even though it is used in the def boyer_moore.
The program apparently doesn't save the variables for later use. I'm sorry if this sounds confusing, I'm quite new to python. The text that is being matched to can be [found here](http://combio.abo.fi/www_includes/text_course/input1.txt)

```
def make_bad_match_table(pattern):

length = len(pattern)
table = {}
for i, c in enumerate(pattern):
    if i == length-1 and not c in table:
        table[c] = length
    else:
        table[c] = length - i - 1

return table




def boyer_moore(pattern, text):
    comparison = 0
    match_table = []
    pattern_length = len(pattern)
    text_length = len(text)
    if pattern_length > text_length:
        return match_table

    table = make_bad_match_table(pattern)
    index = pattern_length - 1
    pattern_index = pattern_length - 1

    while index < text_length:
        if pattern[pattern_index] == text[index]:
            if pattern_index == 0:
                match_table.append(index)
                pattern_index = pattern_length - 1
                index += (pattern_length * 2 - 1)
                comparison +=1
            else:
                pattern_index -= 1
                index -= 1
        else:
            index += table.get(text[index], pattern_length)
            pattern_index = pattern_length - 1

    return match_table
    return comparison

if __name__ == '__main__':

    file = open("CNN.txt", "r")
    target = file.read()
    pattern = "NASA"
    print(pattern,boyer_moore(pattern, target))
    print(len(match_table))
    print(comparison)
```

Comment: `comparison` is only defined in `boyer_moore` and thus is local to that function but you try and call it elsewhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Firstly instead of

```
return match_table
return comparison
```

just do

```
return (match_table, comparison)
```

2.Instead of this:

```
print(pattern,boyer_moore(pattern, target))
print(len(match_table))
print(comparison)
```

just do:

```
 match_table, comparsion = boyer_moore(pattern, target)
 print(pattern)
 print(comparison, len(match_table))
```

Hope it may help you now.

Answer (score 0):

You also can't have a statement after a return statement so you'll have to remove one of the returns at the end of the boyer_moore function.

```
return match_table
return comparison
```

Comment: You're right in the sense that the 2nd `return` is never encountered, but fundamentally this is not the issue